# MVC Routing with no (or a default) action name

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5, I am trying to get some friendly controller/action names working through routing. Banging my head against the wall with this.

Given this controller:

```
MyController
    Index(startPage, pageSize)
    EditAction(itemId)
```

I am using two routes (defined under an inherited AreaRegistration class)

```
context.MapRoute(
            "MyControllerRoute",
            "myArea/MyController/{action}/{itemId}",
            new
            {
                controller = "MyController",
                action = "Index",
                itemId = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new[] {"MySite.Areas.MyArea.Controllers"});

context.MapRoute(
            "MyControllerRoutePaged",
            "myArea/MyController/{action}/{startPage}/{pageSize}",
            new
            {
                controller = "MyController",
                action = "Index",
                pageSize = UrlParameter.Optional,
                startPage = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
              new[] {"MySite.Areas.MyArea.Controllers"});
```

I'd like to achieve these links:

```
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/startPage/pageSize
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/EditAction/itemId

mysite.com/MyArea/MyController2/ (this being the Index action for a given controller)
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController3/ (this being the Index action for another controller)


mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/ (mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/0/20 would also work if paging existis on the controller)
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/5/20
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/EditAction/5
```

The paging links appear on the default Index page. Not on any "action pages".  In particular I am looking to hide the Index action name, so I don't end up with links like:

```
mysite.com/MyArea/MyController/MyController/.../
```

I can achieve this if I drop the {action} placeholder in the routes but the routes end up clashing. I have tried using ActionLink and RouteLink (defining the route name) but there's always one route that matches first and breaks the next one. If I change the ordering of the routes this still happens but the other way around.

I am using a route debugger and I can see where things are failing but I keep going around in circles trying to get it working.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [Attribute Routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) for custom routes.

Comment: thanks. This has helped, now I just have a problem loading the default controller and action for "MyArea"